# How to install DirectX in quiet mode?

Tags: installation, directx, redistributable

I want to install the DirectX 9c user package in quiet mode. Is there any option like /quiet /q /qb etc.
None of these worked.

Note:

With this file DXSETUP.exe /q

not the extractor file directx_9c_redist.exe /q ( this works fine.)

Comment: This isn't really programming related - you'll probably have more luck over on http://www.superuser.com or http://www.serverfault.com

Comment: Disagree, this can be a part of installation routine. We should leave this question open.

Comment: Be sure to read [Not So DirectSetup](https://walbourn.github.io/not-so-direct-setup/) because you almost certainly don't need to "install" DirectX 9.0c.  For recent viewers of this question: Be sure to read [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/legacy-d3dx-on-nuget/) as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this ([taken from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee416805%28VS.85%29.aspx)):

> Set up silently.
>        Launch setup in silent mode so that users do not accidentally skip
>   updating the DirectX runtime. You can
>   do this by launching dxsetup.exe with
>   the following command:
>        path-to-redistributable\dxsetup.exe
>   /silent
>       or by calling DirectSetup and not showing any UI.

Comment: nope, not working ... please tell some more options, so that I try some.

Comment: added one more option, give it a try

Comment: seems dxsetup.exe /silent is not throwing any error msg :) , but no process can be seen in Task manager, unlike 'Window installer' in Silent mode or '.NET framework' in Silent mode. And how to confirm that it is being installed .. I'll get back again.

Comment: I guess you can check the returned error code for confirmation of a successful installation. Is it really critical for you that the process can be seen in Task manager?

Comment: Well I got error code 0. 


OK .. it means it installs .. fine .. thanks.

Comment: Good to hear. Please kindly accept the solution (it will indicate for everyone that this solution works).

Comment: Just ran dxsetup.exe /silent
it seems to kick off a background process, so error code/%ERRORLEVEL% of 0 just means it launched the .exe and not necessarily that it did what it should have.
But it did put files into c:\windows\system32 and c:\windows\syswow64 for me on Server2008R2

Answer (score 2):

If you are using DX11 installer from here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35

/silent will result in an error. You need to use /Q

Answer (score 0):

Yeah,
it works fine as you launch the DXSETUP.exe in the windows command prompt (>cmd).

If I give it something like this:

```
>call "C:\Users\John\Desktop\DirectX_11\DXSETUP.exe" /silent
```